# Error when converting data from CSV to numpy array

Tags: numpy, dataset, python-3.6

I am creating a Numpy array from a CSV file and it does work but at the end of the for loop it is giving the mentioned error.

I have a dataset of 5 columns and been trying to create a Numpy array. However, the code does work with only file columns, once I change my code to:

```
values=[float(x) for x in line.split(',')[0:]]
```

enter code here`it is giving me the following error:

```
File "CNN_ambPressure.py", line 14, in <module>
values=[float(x) for x in line.split(',')[0:]]
File "CNN_ambPressure.py", line 14, in <listcomp>
values=[float(x) for x in line.split(',')[0:]]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 

    import os
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    f=open('Folds5x2_pp.csv')
    data=f.read()
    f.close()
    lines=data.split('\n')
    header=lines[0].split(',')
    lines=lines[1:]
    float_data=np.zeros(((len(lines)),len(header)))
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        values=[float(x) for x in line.split(',')[0:]]
        print(values)
```

I am expecting to just have an output of the Numpy array for the given size without the error. I have attached some pictures to show how it works when I choose to have only 4 columns out of the dataset and how it does not work when I choose to have 5 columns from the dataset.

[Code with the error after I changed line code #14 to have all column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLCH7.png) 
[No error when I change to have only 4 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz0l4.png)

Comment: Please include all the details in your question. Images of code/errors are discouraged.

Comment: Yes, I have explained the error in the post, just added the pictures as an extra. Please let me know if I need to clarify details in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One or more of the subsstrings in a line contains characters that don't belong in a 'float'.  For example if the line include []:

```
In [816]: line = '[1.23, 343.12, 343.2, 34.3]'                                  
In [817]: [float(x) for x in line.split(',')]                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-817-a47cb4a24ec8> in <module>
----> 1 [float(x) for x in line.split(',')]

<ipython-input-817-a47cb4a24ec8> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 [float(x) for x in line.split(',')]

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[1.23'
In [818]: [float(x) for x in line.split(',')[1:-1]]                             
Out[818]: [343.12, 343.2]
In [819]: [float(x) for x in line[1:-1].split(',')]                             
Out[819]: [1.23, 343.12, 343.2, 34.3]
```

Your task, if you should accept it, is to identify which substring is problematic.  You could change the text file to correct it, or add some filtering to remove the offending characters.

---

`np.genfromtxt` is a good way of loading a csv file into an array.  If it can't convert a cell into a float (the default dtype), it puts `nan` into the array. This might help isolate the problem cell(s):

```
In [826]: np.genfromtxt([line], delimiter=',')                                  
Out[826]: array([   nan, 343.12, 343.2 ,    nan])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have started to isolate the substrings. Many thanks!